# How to change WIDTH of UITableView with animation?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I have `UITableView` on the left size and plain `UIView` on the right side in my `UIViewController`

- `UITableView` connects to `.top`, `.leading` and `.bottom` of
  `superview`
- `UIView` connects to `.top`, `.trailing` and `.bottom` of
  `superview`, also it has `.width`
- And `UITableView` `.leading` ==
  `.trailing` of `UIView`

All these constraints you can see on the screenshot:

[image]

Here is my animation code in the controller, as you can see I update `.width` of `UIView` and also I cycle the animation.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var widthConstaint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var watchContainerView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        start()
    }

    func start() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            if self.widthConstaint.constant == 50 {
                self.change(width: 100)
            } else {
                self.change(width: 50)
            }
            self.start()
        }
    }

    func change(width: CGFloat) {
        widthConstaint.constant = width
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }   
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {   
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 300
    }

}
```

As a result you can see this on .gif, what I should for smooth animation, without this glitch?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I tried to reproduce the `UILabel` wrong behavior with my own `UIView` subclass:

```
class MyView: UIView {

    var currentSize: CGSize = .zero

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        guard currentSize != bounds.size else { return }
        currentSize = bounds.size
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        UIColor.purple.setFill()
        UIBezierPath(rect: rect).fill()
        let square = CGRect(x: rect.width - 50, y: rect.origin.y, width: 50, height: rect.height)
        UIColor.blue.setFill()
        UIBezierPath(rect: square).fill()
    }
}
```

The view draws a little blue rectangle at its right, as a text. And… well… the animation is also good!

[image]

But if I change the `contentMode` to `left` (the default value is `scaleToFill`):

[image]

The blue square jumps from one place to the other.

So, I found out this is not only related to the `UILabel`'s `textAlignment`. It's its combinaison with the default `left` content mode of the `UILabel`.

`contentMode` defines how the content should be adjusted if the content's size and the bounds size are different - this is case during the animation, the view redraws itself with its new size right before being resized.

So

```
label.contentMode = .left // default
label.textAlignment = .left
```

will behave as:

```
label.contentMode = .right
label.textAlignment = .right
```

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

I spent some time on your problem. Guess what?

It's not related to the table view at all. It's because of the `.right` text alignment of the label.

You can reproduce the glitch with a simple `UILabel`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let label = UILabel()
    var rightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpView()
        start()
    }

    func start() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            if self.rightConstraint.constant == 50 {
                self.change(width: 100)
            } else {
                self.change(width: 50)
            }
            self.start()
        }
    }

    func change(width: CGFloat) {
        rightConstraint.constant = width
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    func setUpView() {
        label.text = "Label"
        label.textAlignment = .right
        view.addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        rightConstraint = view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.trailingAnchor)
        rightConstraint.isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

*Why?*

To find out the error, I created a `UILabel` subclass and overrode `action(for: CALayer, forKey: String)`. It's where each `UIView` decides which animation to apply in response to a property change ([ref](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#actions)). I was looking for some weird animation behaviors when a label is inside a table view.

If you print `key`, you'd see that actions are requested for the position, the bounds and the contents of the label when `UIKit` is about to commit the animations related to your `UIView.animate(withDuration:)` call.

In fact, `setNeedsDisplay` is called each time the size of an `UILabel` is changed (it makes sens). So I guess there is a conflict between the content redrawing of the label and its frame change.

I think you should recreate the right text alignment of the label without using `textAlignment = .right`.

Horizontally, pin the label to the right only. When `layoutIfNeeded` will be called, only the label's position will change, not its content.

Comment: "It's because of the .right text alignment of the label."  But if I change it to `.center` nothing happens. Removing .leading constraint is good point, to get rid of this glitch, but behaviour will be a little bit different

Comment: I've the same glitch with textAlignment = .center @TikhonovAlexander. If the redraw changes the text position in the UILabel a glitch appears. You can think of the label as an image view. A glitch will appear if you change the image but animate the frame.

Comment: I replaced `UILabel` to `UIButton` and it works well, `UILabel` and `UIButton` are quite similar ui elements, but they are redrawn differently. Oh...

Comment: `UIButton` has a `UILabel`. If you take a look a the view hierarchy debugger you will see it and that it has the same size as the text which is not your case.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the @[Gaétanz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3857555/ga%C3%A9tanz) answer. The abnormal behaviour is due to the Lable inside the cell.

You can remove the glitches by changing the Labels leading constraint relation to >= and change the priority to 999 from 1000.

Please refer the screenshot attached for your reference.

[image]

When you add constraint with a priority less than 1000 it will be an optional constraint. Priority 1000 is the required priority for a constraint. Here if you added a priority of 999, all the other constraints with priority 1000 will layout first and the less priority constraint will layout last.

Comment: Keeping leading constraint priority 1000.0 has the same effect as optional constraint (<1000.0). And if change relation to >=0 it works... but label sticks on the right side, not on all sides, it's not what I expected. Anyway it looks like the problem with leading constraint of label.

Comment: If you provide the content it will work as expected.

Comment: If I have a different background color UILabel unlike UITableViewCell, it won't work as expected

Comment: Exactly. We need to compromise there. But still we can achieve this by providing a container view for label. 

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the width of your side view outside of the animation block. put you `widthConstaint.constant = width` inside your animation block.

```
func change(width: CGFloat) {
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            self.widthConstaint.constant = width
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }   
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't help me. Your method isn't right way for updating constraints with animation

Answer (score 0):

According to your code the View is animated but the constraint is not put in the UIView animation block. So it looks like a glitch cause it changes the frame directly. Please try to change the code as below and try.

```
func change(width: CGFloat) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            widthConstaint.constant = width
            self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }   
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't help me. Your method isn't right way for updating constraints with animation and `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` also triggers update layout of `tableView`, so `self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()` is unnecessary here